# JAVA Spring returning image bytes - Error 406 not acceptable

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-mvc, base64

I'm having next issue - each image sends request:

```
<img src="getImage/9.jpg"/>
```

Spring MVC Controller:

```
    @Secured( "ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getImage/{img_name:.+}")
    public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable String img_name)  {

        byte[] data;

        try {
            String realpath = "D:\\Project\\images\\" + img_name;
            Path path = Paths.get(realpath);
            data = Files.readAllBytes(path)


        }catch (IOException e){
            data = null;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

On the side of browser I'm receiving next error:

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

What could be the reason of such issue? What data should I send from the server side to make this `<img src="getImage/9.jpg"?>` work properly.

Comment: Did you try to add "@ResponseBody" before your returnType? public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage(@PathVariable String img_name)

Comment: Check from your developer tools, what is the Accept-Type and Content-Type of the request. The web service must produce as "image/jpg"

Comment: Just did - unfortunately didn't help. Maybe the reason is in the type of data that I'm sending to client? What type of data it should be? or byte[] is the correct type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly add this code in the spring-context.xml file which registers a ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter

```
<mvc:annotation-driven> <mvc:message-converters> <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"> <property name="supportedMediaTypes"> <list> <value>image/jpeg</value> <value>image/png</value> </list> </property> </bean> </mvc:message-converters> </mvc:annotation-driven
```

and the class should be

```
 @Secured( "ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(value = "/getImage/{img_name:.+}")
public  ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable String img_name)
        throws InternalServerError {

    byte[] data;
    try {
        String realpath = "D:\\Project\\images\\" + img_name;
        Path path = Paths.get(realpath);
        data = Files.readAllBytes(path)


    }catch (IOException e){
        data = null;
    }

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(data , headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Saved my ass so far - it works!)) Thanks a lot! Added bean to dispatcher-servlet.xml file

Comment: :) Glad I could help